# Simulate file system structure with core data (Files and Folders)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data, filesystems

I want to simulate files and folders structure inside my app. Actually I already did it with real folders and files but itunes does not support it and I also want the user to be able to export and import files through iTunes. 
So the problem is folders are not visible in itunes (in Windows they are visible but they cannot be selected anyway.) Hence is not possible to export all files or import a file inside folders

So, I wonder if its possible to simulate a file system using CoreData where folders can contain X subfolders and Y files. (Since iTunes does not support folders they have to be no real folders)

How can I model my data to accomplish this?

I would appreciate any link, help or idea.

thanks

Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

iTunes will not support folders. But, iTunes can support a zip with files and folders. Check for some Drilldown applications in [Apple developers site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code), or google it.

Comment: probably my question was not clear enough... I am aware of that. That is why I want to simulate folders and files using core data. Once i have them I believe navigation is not that complicated. ;)